# SQL : Cartesian product + Join + Flatten

Tags: mysql, sql

Under MYSQL 5.6, I have the following 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    id        INTEGER,
    login     VARCHAR(32),
    isservice BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE Certificate
(
    userid        INTEGER,
    serviceid     INTEGER,
    certificate   VARCHAR(32)
);
```

With the following data :

User:

```
id  |  login   |  isservice
---------------------------
1   | john     | false
2   | bob      | false
3   | serviceA | true
4   | serviceB | true
```

Certificate: (*example Data, real data in Certificate column are unknown*)

```
userid | serviceid | Certificale
---------------------------
1      | 3         | Alpha
1      | 4         | Bravo
```

I createdthe following SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/719a8/2

I'm searching for the **request** (not stored procedure) that would give me the following :

```
id | login | certif_serviceA | certif_serviceB
-----------------------------------------------
1  | john  | Alpha           | Bravo
2  | bob   | NULL            | NULL
```

So far, I have tried basing my request on :

```
SELECT  user.id, user.login,
        service.login as serviceName
FROM User, User as service WHERE service.isservice=1 AND user.isservice=0
```

But i'm stuck there :s

Comment: you should better redesign your DB schema. to keep `Users` in the same table as `Services`  is **very bad** idea

Comment: @Alex : I think you are right, however in my real case it makes a bit more sense than in the example I provided (services are users because in my app they are very very close). And saddly I can't modify the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already commented you definitely should redesign your DB.

What you are asking for is `pivot table` which is not so easy to achieve using mysql. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7675121/4421474)

But I have this approach for you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dc0b2/1

```
SELECT  user.id, user.login,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Services.login) as ServicesName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(certificate.certificate) as Certificates
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Certificate
ON Certificate.userid = User.id
LEFT JOIN User Services
ON Certificate.serviceid = Services.id
WHERE NOT User.isservice
GROUP BY User.id
```

or

```
SELECT  user.id, user.login,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Services.login,':',certificate.certificate)) as ServicesName
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Certificate
ON Certificate.userid = User.id
LEFT JOIN User Services
ON Certificate.serviceid = Services.id
WHERE NOT User.isservice
GROUP BY User.id
```

Probably you can accept it for current case.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT  user.id, user.login,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Services.login) as ServicesName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(certificate.certificate) as Certificates
FROM User
LEFT JOIN User Services
ON Services.isservice
LEFT JOIN Certificate
ON Certificate.userid = User.id
  AND Certificate.serviceid = Services.id
WHERE NOT User.isservice
GROUP BY User.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c062/4

Comment: There is a problem if not all certificates are defined for a User :
I get : (1,john,serviceB,Bravo) instead of (1,john,(serviceA,serviceB),(Null,Bravo))

Comment: google pivot table if you really need that. in 99% cases there is no need. in your case you should redesign your DB. but ok, I'll set another query for you even if it is weird. give mi a minute.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
SELECT id,
       login,
       MIN(Certificate.certificate) AS certif_serviceA,
       MAX(Certificate.certificate) AS certif_serviceB
FROM USER
LEFT JOIN Certificate ON USER.id = Certificate.userid
WHERE isservice = 0
GROUP BY USER.id
```